# convergent series with nonzero limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, infinity

I was watching through professor dave's video https://youtu.be/L-JqHo4-W4k?list=PLybg94GvOJ9FoGQeUMFZ4SWZsr30jlUYK&t=433 and at 7:13 he claims that in order for a series to be convergent, its sequence must go to zero in the limit of infinity.

I can't entirely agree with this claim as I think it's fairly trivial to produce a series that converges while having it's sequence have a nonzero limit in infinity.

The example I am giving is below,
f(x) = 1/2^x
g(x) = f(infinite-x) (where infinite is the cardinality of N)
g(x) must converge as it has the same set of values as f. But the sequence at g(infinite) =
f(infinite-infinite) = f(0) = 1, does not go to zero.

I am trying to say like what if you flipped a converging function around horizontally, then it wouldn't go to zero at infinity, but the series on that function would converge.

Have I missed something about the nature of infinity? Is this already known and this video is a simplification of the full theorem?

Thank you, friends.

edit: I think my maths communication may not be the best so here are some examples
[image: table demonstration]

note: the sum of this sequence (the series) is 2.

I understand that potentially this may not be the most correct way of describing a function like this, but I think it does demonstrate my point?
The ratio test seems to work better for me but I would still like to know where my explanation is wrong.

Comment: Look closely at what he states. Note that series and sequence are different concepts.

Comment: I think you're confusing the convergence of the series (the thing you're summing up) and the sequence of terms that you're summing up (inside the series). For the overall series to converge, you do indeed need that the terms in the sum become smaller and smaller, and eventually tend to zero.

Comment: Evaluating an infinite limit is not really like evaluating something "at" infinity. Your "flipping around horizontally" introduces a different structure to the input and so the series can't really "get off the ground." I'm also not sure you can extend arithmetic to infinity in any "nice" way, so this "infinite - x" might not make sense.

Comment: To elaborate a tad more just using the terms in the series, if you have $a_n$ for each natural number $n$, what would the first element of the flipped sequence be? Maybe you can think of the reversed order as $1/n$ for natural $n$ (under the standard ordering on $\mathbb R$) but there is no minimal element.

Comment: What is $g(1)$?

Comment: probably 0? I'm not too sure.

Comment: You need to at least be able to define it if you want to argue your construction of $g$ is meaningful.  Arguably, the only meaningful assignment to your series is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty g(n) = 0$ if you define it conventionally as the limit of partial sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Divergence Test/Theorem from Calculus states that if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$, as proved in Paul's Online Notes: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/convergenceofseries.aspx

*Edit:* The problem presented in your example is in the ellipses. There is no *next element* if you reverse the ordering of the naturals. If my index set is $\{0\} \cup \{ 1/n : n \geq 1\}$, for example, after $0$, there is no next element. Moreover, arithmetic with infinity is not really tenable. For example, if you want to think of infinity as a limit, then we could maybe say $\infty = \lim_{n\to\infty} n$. Maybe then (loosely speaking) $\infty - \infty = \lim_{n\to\infty} n - \lim_{n\to\infty} n = \lim_{n\to\infty} 0 = 0$. However, $\infty = \lim_{n\to\infty} n + 1$ so then $\infty - \infty = \lim_{n\to\infty} n+1 - \lim_{n\to\infty} n = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1 = 1$, but clearly $0 \neq 1$.

Another obstacle to this reordering scheme is the following: series that converge conditionally can be rearranged and obtain different values in their sum. Though that's not a problem in your example since that series converges absolutely.

Comment: I understand this. I was trying to say that I wasn't entirely satisfied with this idea and I gave an example of a contradiction to this test. Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: @Glubs I've edited my answer to elaborate more on what I was saying in the comments and hopefully address the issue in your proposed counterexample.

Comment: Yeah! 100% Ok thank you yes. I think I understand the problem with my definition now. Much love good friend